# Creating a table view for invoice - Northwind

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have a little problem with my last tasks. I am using an old Northwind database.
First, I had to create a query, that will give me all the important information for the invoice. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT       b.OrderID, 
             b.CustomerID, 
            c.CompanyName, 
            c.Address, 
            c.City,  
            c.PostalCode, 
            c.CountryID as CustomersCountryID, 
            concat(d.FirstName,  ' ', d.LastName) as Salesperson,   
            a.CompanyName as ShippingVia, 
            e.ProductID, 
            f.ProductName, 
            e.Quantity, 
            e.UnitPrice * e.Quantity * (1 - e.Discount) as ExtendedPrice
from Shippers a 
inner join Orders b on a.ShipperID = b.ShipVia 
inner join Customers c on c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
inner join Employees d on d.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
inner join [Order Details] e on b.OrderID = e.OrderID
inner join Products f on f.ProductID = e.ProductID
order by b.OrderID
```

It works, it gives me all the orders made with informations. But now, I need to create a table view for an invoice of particular OrderId. When I write something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW FAKTURA AS
SELECT       b.OrderID, 
             b.CustomerID, 
            c.CompanyName, 
            c.Address, 
            c.City,  
            c.PostalCode, 
            c.CountryID as CustomersCountryID, 
            concat(d.FirstName,  ' ', d.LastName) as Salesperson,   
            a.CompanyName as ShippingVia, 
            e.ProductID, 
            f.ProductName, 
            e.Quantity, 
            e.UnitPrice * e.Quantity * (1 - e.Discount) as ExtendedPrice
from Shippers a 
inner join Orders b on a.ShipperID = b.ShipVia 
inner join Customers c on c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
inner join Employees d on d.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
inner join [Order Details] e on b.OrderID = e.OrderID
inner join Products f on f.ProductID = e.ProductID
WHERE b.OrderID = 10248
```

I am just creating a separate view file for that particular OrderID. It doesn't look like a real life invoice at all.

[image]

It should resemble something like this:

[image]

I need to separate general data about invoice and customer from data about order itself, product ID, quantity etc.
Is it possible to create something similar in SQL Server Management Studio? How can I do it?

Comment: And how does it look like? Can you post it?

Comment: @FDavidov You mean my "view"? It looks pretty much like a simple query with selected OrderID, it creates a file in "Views" folder, but it doesn't resemble a table like the one in my post at all.

Comment: This is something which should probably be handled in your presentation layer, whatever that might be.  SQL Server is good at generating result sets, but much less good at formatting them.

Comment: You mean to create a report instead of a mssql view? Because a view only display as a table with columns and rows, and has no format layout as the image you post

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Yes, I think that's what I need.

Comment: What you posted is a (paper-like) FORM, not a table. Please post the actual result you are getting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well I am only using SQL Server, That's why I am puzzled.

Comment: @FDavidov I've added it to the main post

Comment: OK OK... Your query returns what you need within the TABLE of your form, and you need the other parts (e.g. header with customer's details, subtotal, tax, etc.) Those additions CANNOT be returned as part of the view unless you add them to each and every record. The alternative is to fetch the header information (customer's details), get data from your view (table contents) into a local variable table which would be used to populate the middle part of the form as well as to perform the remaining calculations (sub-total, tax, etc.).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is there any other way I can present something resembling the expected result in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes.  You can format your output just as sensibly laid out text, but you might need proc to get that level of control.

Comment: @FDavidov That sounds pretty advanced, I am still learning SQL. Now, can I create a view that will give me two separate tables, one for the customers info, second with order details?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well my exact task sounds like this "Create a table containing all the necessary data to display" (translated from polish). My superior wouldn't give me something so complicated to do, since he gave me all those tasks to do. There must be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Besides SQL Server, what other tools do you have available?  Also note that your supervisor may not realize the difficulty of what he is asking you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No other programs worth mentioning, And My SQL Server is pretty basic, I have googled out something called "SQL Server Reporting Services" and I'm checking if I have that installed.

Comment: Creating a view with two results table: NO!!! What you can do is create a view that will include **all the needed information (i.e. customer details as well as trailer information like sub-total) as part of each and every record of the result**.

Comment: @FDavidov So pretty much what I did? What would be a difference in query?

Comment: One more thing: You may wish to explore the use of CTE (check this for instance:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: The difference is that you need to add to your query the _trailer_ information (sub-total, etc.).

Comment: @FDavidov I am afraid You'll need to walk me through it, informations from the Invoice query is all I need. How exactly I should edit my view query?

Comment: Well, SO is not aimed to be a TEACHING environment but only a place from which you can get ideas or answers to specific questions. Still, stay tuned and I'll add an answer below (few minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Your query already provides the header (customer info) and table body parts, so what you could do is (NOTE: this is NOT what I would do but, considering the need to have a very simple solution):

1. Phrase a query that would perform all the needed calculations for the trailing part based on the INVOICE number (this can be similar to what you already have except that it would SUM the amounts, calculate taxes and shipping cost),
2. Once you have that query ready, INNER JOIN it to the one you already have (using the invoice ID as a key); Note that you will have to add the additional fields to the top SELECTs list.

The result will be what you already have + the subtotal, tax, shipping and total in each and every record.

Again, this is NOT the most efficient and elegant solution, but matches your needs (simplicity and final result).

Comment: Not sure if I know what to do, as I said, still learning the SQL. But I will try. If I'll get my result, I'll let you know!

Comment: Seeing your initial work (the posted query), I'm sure you will get there soon. Good luck!!!

Comment: I am stuck, I still have no idea how it should look like. Can you give me an example?